# Objective-C instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I opened my project after a week and it seems, for all the new `UIViewController` I create in the `StoryBoard`, `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` is returning is nil. All the `ViewControllers` which are already in the project are working fine.

```
GCHConnectViewController* gchCVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GchConnect"];
navigationController.viewControllers = @[gchCVC];
```

First line is returning nil, my initial thought was that `self.storyboard` is returning nil, so I tried this and put breakpoint.

```
if (self.storyboard != nil) {
    GCHConnectViewController* gchCVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GchConnect"];
    navigationController.viewControllers = @[gchCVC];
}
```

and its going to inside the if and crash at the second line..

I've also added the class and `storyboard` id correctly.

[image]

If I try to load another `ViewController` which was already there, it works, but not new ones.

Can't seem to figure out what is the problem. Any help is appreciated.

I've a navigation drawer. switching to other ViewController except with the one with identifier 'GchConnect' (ie. indexPath.section == 1 and indexpath.row == 0 ) works. They are all in the same storyboard

Comment: you need push one view to another view controller?

Comment: remove check mark from use storyboard id and than check else use `[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil]` to get refered storyboard

Comment: Did you by inadvertence localized your storyboard, and added the new view controller only a on localized version which is not the current one you are testing?

Comment: Uncheck storyboard ID and then try. It may work!! and `navigationController.viewControllers` statement sets viewControllers to navigation controller, usually used to initialize naigation controller. you should push viewcontroller on navigation controller

Comment: Click inside **Module** textbox and press enter.it may solve your problem.

Comment: what does the crash say ? @

Comment: unchecking the storyboard Id did not work.

Comment: @TejaNandamuri it says, NSScanner: nil string argument

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, problem was that I added localization, silly thing wasted a lot of time.

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple storyboards, `self.storyboard` returns the one that the  current `UIViewController` is in. You need you check the name of storybaord for "GchConnect". And instantiate that storyboard with [storyboardWithName:bundle:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIStoryboard/storyboardWithName:bundle:)

```
UIStoryboard storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:bundle:nil];
GCHConnectViewController* gchCVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GchConnect"];
```

Comment: @HeisenBerg if you are only using one storyboard. Then your code looks correct to me. Sometimes interface builder is buggy. If you are able to reproduce it with a smaller project settings. I will recommend submit it to https://bugreport.apple.com/ and see.

Comment: @HeisenBerg and other suggestions are: (1) make sure Xcode is up to date; (2) restart your Xcode if you have not done so; (3) make sure your id don't have extract spaces at the end; ...

Answer (score 0):

use this code

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
HomepageViewController *vc = [mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GchConnect"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Comment: what is the result of this code? i mean black screen?

Comment: and what is the crashlog?

Comment: NSScanner: nil string argument

Comment: remove your code and use my code for each case also import that viewcontroller

Comment: It crashes in the second line, doesn't go to the third line where we pushViewController

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

if you present the `viewcontroller` use below code,

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                                @"YourStoryBoardName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

GCHConnectViewController* gchCVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GchConnect"];

[self presentViewController:gchCVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

or  if you Push the `viewcontroller` use below code,

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:
                                    @"YourStoryBoardName" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

GCHConnectViewController* gchCVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GchConnect"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:gchCVC animated:YES];
```

hope its helpful

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
if (self.storyboard != nil) {
    GCHConnectViewController* gchCVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GchConnect"];
    navigationController.viewControllers = @[gchCVC];
}
```

try to use:

```
if (self.storyboard != nil) {
    GCHConnectViewController* gchCVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"GchConnect"];
    navigationController.pushViewController(gchCVC, animated: true)
}
```

What you should do is either push or present view controller. At the moment you're trying to replace all viewcontrollers that are in your navigationcontroller,

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I add localization and changes I add to the storyboard were getting updated to the simulator/device.

It fixed it by:

selecting the StoryBoard, then

Editor > Localization Locking > Reset Locking Controls

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that the code module for the ViewController has been added to the target you are building for.  This fixed it for me.